# Insert Pagebreak into a google Doc to inplace of findText()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to insert a page break at a specific line of text.

This is what I have:

```
function replaceTextwithPageBreak(body, text){
  var searchText = body.findText(text);
  var textEl = searchText.getElement();
  var textCh = textEl.getParent().getChildIndex(textEl);
  body.insertPageBreak(textCh); 
}

var breakText = "break";

replaceTextwithPageBreak(body, breakText);
```

This works, however.. in the Test Document Template I have set up, the text is as follows:

```
value1
value2
break (<-- the value I'm trying to insert the page break at)
value4
```

What is happening is everything is getting put onto the new page instead of just everything after 'break'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script of `replaceTextwithPageBreak`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function replaceTextwithPageBreak(body, text) {
  var searchText = body.findText(text);
  var textEl = searchText.getElement().getParent();
  var textCh = body.getChildIndex(textEl);
  body.insertPageBreak(textCh);
}
```

- By this modification, in your showing sample template, the page break is inserted to `break`.
- If there are multiple `break` in the Document and you want to insert the line break to them, how about the following sample script?

  ```js
  function replaceTextwithPageBreaks(body, text) {
    let s = body.findText(text);
    while (s) {
      const e = s.getElement();
      const idx = body.getChildIndex(e.getParent());
      body.insertPageBreak(idx);
      // e.removeFromParent(); // If you want to remove "break" paragraph, please use this.
      s = body.findText(text, s);
    }
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getChildIndex(child) of Class Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild)